# Taking advantage of the Entity Framework's many-to-many relationships when the joining table has an extra field

Tags: entity-framework, graph, entity-framework-4, many-to-many, relational-database

A scenario:

In my database I have a table joining Customers and Movies together, with an extra field specifying the weight of the relation. EG:

```
CustomersMovies
  | -CustomerID
  | -MovieID
  | -Weight
```

If I only had the first two fields, the Entity Framework would recognise the many-to-many relationship and I would be able to call Customer.Movies and Movie.Customers. With the third field, this relationship is broken.

Ideally, I would love to be able to go Customer.Movies[0].Weight or something similar to return the joining parameter. Even if this is not supported, I would still like the many-to-many relationship for other functions.

Is anything like this supported within the Entity Framework? I am almost about to create two tables, CustomersMovies (which just joins the two tables) and a CustomerMovieWeights table which specifies the weight for a given customer and movie, but the redundant data isn't ideal.

Kind Regards,
Harry

Comment: Not supported, either you have to exclude the Weight member from the model, or go with two tables, or map the same table twice in the model.

Answer (score 0):

If you dropped the **Weight** column from the junction table, then you would only need to map **Customers** and **Movies** table.

If not, you will need to map all three tables: **Customer**, **CustomerMovies** and **Movies**.

But of course, you will not be able to do this:

```
var customer = ctx.Customers.First();
var customerMovies = customer.Movies;
```

You will have to do this:

```
var customer = ctx.Customers.First();
var customerMovies = customer.CustomerMovies.Movies;
```

Because **Customer** will not have a direct navigational property to **Movie** - it will have a navigational property to **CustomerMovie** (and vice versa).

Honestly though, i would go with your last idea. Have the **CustomerMovies** table contain only the FK's (CustomerId, MovieId), and another "meta-data-like" table for weights.

This way you can map your many-to-many properly in the EDMX.

Comment: I'm not having much success, but is it possible to create a view which is just SELECT CustomerID, MovieID from CustomersMovies and then add that into the model? Because the view obviously doesn't have any foreign keys it isn't playing nice.

Comment: yes, it's possible (i think), but then you won't be able to perform UPDATE operations on the "CustomerMovies" entity, because a view is basically read-only (e.g you can't do UPDATE vwCustomerMovies - or can you?